# Where to put Lucee cfm files

Tags: lucee

I just installed Lucee, and got to the welcome page.  I cannot find instructions anywhere for what directory to put my .cfm files in, so that I can run them from Lucee.  Could someone tell me where to put them, or direct me to some documentation?

Never mind -- I managed to find it.  In my case opt/lucee/tomcat/webapps/ROOT, as a result of the standard installation.  So why couldn't someone have said this somewhere?

Comment: Consider to write them an email about that. Lucee's documentation is actually hard to understand so try to help them with your enthusiasm.

Comment: Problem is it is completely dependant on the type of install you have done, what application server and web server you are using, etc... there is no "standard" location as such.

Comment: Pat -- I will contact them when I have some time.  However, until I've used the product for awhile, I would not care to write documentation myself.

Comment: Andrew, I assumed that it would differ from one installation to another.  if However, I did a completely standard installation, making not one change to the various questions.  So that at least could be documented.  Further, if we are using Tomcat, some info about where Tomcat might look for program files could be offered.

Answer (score 0):

I am hosted by hostek.com and they have the home folder under /home/mydomain.

But I think that's an IIS solution, not a Lucee one.

Betty, I would be more than happy to help a PhD in Applied Mathematics with Lucee.
I too have a project that I'm working on that I think will help a lot of people.

Comment: Phillip, I already have my system running in ColdFusion, so my next step is to see what works and what does not in Lucee.  I am grateful for help at any time -- let me know how to contact you.